# Maven dependecny in the wrapper class under referenced library

Tags: spring-boot

When i download springboot application from spring initializer , instead of maven dependency file i am getting maven dependency wrapper jar under the referenced library , how can i solve this problem?

[image]

Not able to figure out. Just a beginner

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: You haven't imported it as a maven project but as a regular project.